# Are $\Re(z)$ and $\Im(z)$ solutions of $z' = az$?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

I'm having trouble with a question (I have to answer "true" or "false" and explain it):

> We have $a:I \to C,$ a continuous function on $I$, interval of $R$. If the function $z:I \to C$ is a solution of the equation $(E) z'=az$, then $\Re(z)$ and $\Im(z)$ are solutions of $(E)$.

Could you give me some hints? I've been trying to solve that for 1h and can't figure out anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a$ to be the constant function $a\colon x\in I \mapsto i \in \mathbb{C}$, and solve the differential equation $z^\prime= i z$. $z\colon x\mapsto e^{ix}$ is solution; can $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ be a solution?

Comment: z is a solution? But doesn't Re(z) = cos(x)?

Comment: Yes, $x\mapsto e^{ix}$ is a solution. Does (the real-valued function) $x\mapsto \cos x$ satisfy $\cos^\prime = i\cos$?

Comment: It doesn't. So $Re(z)$ can't be a solution i assume.

Comment: Indeed :) (that gives you a counter-example).

Comment: You're a life savior (I don't know if that's how you say it, I'm French). Gonna be really helpful in the future. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!